# How can redefine initial state on my reducer, when I change the component

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, redux, redux-actions

**More details :**

I have a component called `header` inside I have a menu, when I'm in mobile device I have a burger menu.

When I clicked on this burger menu, I set a state at `true` and the menu become open, when I clicked on a cross, the state become `false` and the menu is close.

**Now the problem :**

If I change component is save always the previous state, If menu it's open and click on `home` for example, the state it's actually at `true` and in my home the menu it's open, and I don't want this comportement.

Do you have some advice ?

Look the code :

```js
// ACTION : 

export const setBurgerMenu = createAction(
  SET_BURGER_MENU,
  () => ({})
);

export const getBurgerMenu = () => {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(setBurgerMenu());
  };
};

// REDUCER : 
// Initial state contain isOpenMenu at false
const reducer = handleActions({
  [SET_BURGER_MENU]: (state) => {
    return {
      ...state,
      isOpenMenu: !state.isOpenMenu
    };
  },
  [BREADCRUMBS_WILL_UPDATE]: (state) => {
    return {
      ...state,
      isWillUpdate: true
    };
  },
  [BREADCRUMBS_UPDATED]: (state) => {
    return {
      ...state,
      isWillUpdate: false
    };
  },
  [CLEAR_USER_DATA]: () => {
    return {
      ...initialState
    };
  }
}, initialState);
```

Comment: Why are your actions in square brackets?

Comment: We don't have a unique way to write our reducer, at the office the apps it's develop  like this, but I prefer switch/case method.

Comment: I asked the question because it may be an issue; does it work properly when they are in square brackets?

Comment: Yes of course, all my reducer in application is writing like that :)

Comment: @Jonathan Can you add your component that is using this value?

Comment: I’am a true idiot ! Ive found the solution is si basic... I made a seconde reducer called ‘closeMenu’ for exemple and I initialize my state at false and inside my component in ‘componentWillMount()’ I called the action in charge to update my reducer. I edit the post when at my home.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `componentWillUnmount` or the `componentWillMount` methods on the components

Using `componentWillUnmount` on first component:

```
componentWillUnmount() {
  if (this.props.isMenuOpen) this.props.setBurgerMenu()
}
```

Using `componentWillMount` on second component:

```
componentWillMount() {
  if (this.props.isMenuOpen) this.props.setBurgerMenu()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I found the solution 20min after I've post. 
I'm a real idiot, the problem is very basic. 
I had to make a reducer for when I click (value at `true`) and another at the value at `false` when my component is mounted I call the `false` value, and if I click the `true`, No simpler than that...